# Missing permissions required by GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled: android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Tags: java, android, geolocation, android-manifest

Trying to use geofence location but app crashes when selecting the geofence area.
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission already declared in the manifest file but when launching the application, it does not request to allow the permission.

Code

```
  private void enableUserLocation(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        }
        else {
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, FINE_LOCATION_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
            else {
                if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, FINE_LOCATION_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

AndroidManifestXml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.quarantinemonitoringapp" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

Screenshot

[image: error on code]

Comment: That is a Lint warning, one that may have some bugs. Does the app run correctly?

Comment: No it crashes when selecting the location.

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Mr Ken. I'm currently not able to setup a project with a minimal requirements to get this error. But I believe you need to check for the `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission like you did with `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`